# How to make labels of x-axis texts vertically for gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I tried

```
 plot [][1:3] 'word-based.txt' using 1:xtic(2) with line
```

it draws the required graph but with horizontal direction of x-axis labels which is texts as

shown in picture. How to make its direction vertically so i can be read more easily.

i used windows terminal .[image: fig]

Edit:

Data used

```
2.02            economic
2.04            education
1.94            sports
2.01            culture
2.07            artandmusic
1.93            political
1.94            articles
1.83            press
1.86            novel1
1.86            novel2
1.85            novel3
1.85            shortstories
1.76            literature
1.60            history
1.81            bookcollection1
1.77            bookcollection2
```

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example of your `gnuplot` code and the data, such that the people willing to help you can reproduce the figure.

Comment: @HenriMenke i have posted it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only about gnuplot and should be migrated to stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use

```
set xtics rotate
```

You can also

```
set xtics rotate by <angle>
```

## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'

set xtics rotate # crucial line

plot [][1:3] '-' using 1:xtic(2) with line   
2.02 economic
2.04 education
1.94 sports
2.01 culture
2.07 artandmusic
1.93 political
1.94 articles
1.83 press
1.86 novel1
1.86 novel2
1.85 novel3
1.85 shortstories
1.76 literature
1.60 history
1.81 bookcollection1
1.77 bookcollection2
```

## Output

> [image]